# filter pandas.DataFrame with python list in cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pasdas.DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name' : ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Eve'],
        'age' : ['20', '35', '40'],
        'stuff' : [['computer', 'phone', 'bike'], ['bike', 'skateboard', 'phone'], 
                   ['computer', 'phone', 'skateboard']]}

frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

How can I select rows where age > 30 and stuff contains 'computer'?

I've tried solve this with DataFrame.loc :

```
filteredFrame = frame.loc[(frame.age > 30)&('computer' in frame.stuff)]
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Almost a dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877712/check-if-an-item-in-a-list-is-available-in-a-column-which-is-of-type-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column `year` to numbers, if necessary:

```
frame.age = frame.age.astype(int)
```

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) or [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
filteredFrame = frame.loc[(frame.age > 30)&(frame.stuff.map(lambda x: 'computer' in x))]
filteredFrame = frame.loc[(frame.age > 30)&(frame.stuff.apply(lambda x: 'computer' in x))]
```

Or list comprehension:

```
filteredFrame = frame.loc[(frame.age > 30)&(['computer' in x for x in frame.stuff])]
```

---

```
print (filteredFrame)
  name  age                          stuff
2  Eve   40  [computer, phone, skateboard]
```